# Discord.py - TimeoutError when trying to take a user_input

Tags: python, discord.py

I want to have two user input in discord.py from two different users so i made another check function

```
def s_check(b):
    def inner(m):
      return  m.author == b
    return inner

user_1 = await bot.wait_for('message', check=check(ctx.author), timeout=30)

mentioned_user = user_1.mentions[0]

user_2 = await bot.wait_for('message', check = s_check(mentioned_user), timeout = 30) # here it dosen't detects the user input and gives a timeout error
```

why is my code not detecting the second user input and what is the correct way to do that

Comment: I'm assuming it is `s_check(ctx.author)` in the first wait_for?

Comment: I changed the check in the first wait_for and it works correctly, not reproducible

Comment: @Ceres no, I definded another check functuon  for user_2 and another for user_1

Comment: It works fine for me, only throws the error when the user doesn't respond within 30 seconds

Comment: the solution works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't define the `check(ctx.author)` so we don't know what it is referring too, please add more code to your question so we can help better.

For your problem, you are giving a function that returns another function as the check, whereas [documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=wait_for#discord.ext.commands.Bot.wait_for) indicates you must give a function that returns a boolean for the check.

Here is how I would do it with [lamba functions](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lambda.asp)

```
user_1 = await bot.wait_for('message', check=lambda m: m.author == ctx.author, timeout=30)

mentioned_user = user_1.mentions[0]

user_2 = await bot.wait_for('message', check=lambda m: m.author == mentioned_user , timeout = 30)
```